# How do you properly use 'match' to build a hash for every line in a file using ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking through output on a Cisco ASA of `show conn protocol tcp`.

Every line has this format:

```
TCP OUTSIDE 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO
```

I would like for my hashes to look like this:

```
h = {:dst => 4.2.2.2:443,
     :src => 10.17.21.44:63314,
     :bytes => 11356,
     :flags => UIO,
    }
```

Here is my attempt to do this, but I'm getting "undefined method 'captures' for nil:NilClass".

I think this is saying the line is not matching, but I'm pretty sure my regex is correct. One issue I know I will have is that the `src` and `dst` in this setup will match both addresses. I'm not sure how I can make `dst` match the first address, and `src` match the first address.

```
h = {}
fp = File.open('conns.txt','r+')
fp.each_with_index do |line, i|
    dst = line.match(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d+/).captures
    src = line.match(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d+/).captures
    bytes = line.match(/(?<=bytes\s)(\d+)/).captures
    flags = line.match(/(?<=flags\s)(\w+)/).captures
    h[i+1] = {dst: dst, src: src, bytes: bytes, flags: flags}
end
```

Here is the irb session:

```
irb(main):001:0> h = {}
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> fp = File.open('conns.txt','r+')
=> #<File:conns.txt>
irb(main):003:0> #TCP OUTSIDE  4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE  10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO
irb(main):004:0* fp.each_with_index do |line, i|
irb(main):005:1*     dst = line.match(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d+/).captures
irb(main):006:1>     src = line.match(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d+/).captures
irb(main):007:1>     bytes = line.match(/(?<=bytes\s)(\d+)/).captures
irb(main):008:1>     flags = line.match(/(?<=flags\s)(\w+)/).captures
irb(main):009:1>     h[i+1] = {dst: dst, src: src, bytes: bytes, flags: flags}
irb(main):010:1> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `captures' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):5:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):4:in `each'
    from (irb):4:in `each_with_index'
    from (irb):4
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):011:0>
```

---

If I remove `captures` it no longer fails but I get `#<MatchData` prepended to each field. The hash looks like this:

```
 {1=>{:dst=>#<MatchData "4.2.2.2:443">, :src=>#<MatchData "4.2.2.2:443">, :bytes=>#<MatchData "11365" 1:"11365">, :flags=>#<MatchData "UIO" 1:"UIO">}}
```

---

Using `scan` works and I figured out the `dst` vs `src` issue too:

```
h = {}
fp = File.open('conns.txt','r+')
#TCP OUTSIDE  4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE  10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO
fp.each_with_index do |line, i|
    ip = line.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}:\d+/)
    dst = ip[0]
    src = ip[1]
    bytes = line.scan(/(?<=bytes\s)(\d+)/)
    flags = line.scan(/(?<=flags\s)(\w+)/)
    h[i+1] = {dst: dst, src: src, bytes: bytes, flags: flags}
end
```

Comment: I think you need to add `.readlines` to `File.open('conns.txt','r+')`

Comment: The OP is using the better method of `each_with_index` which will read the file line-by-line, instead of slurping it into an array using `readlines` and then having to iterate over that. `readlines` is not scalable, while `each` or `each_with_index` is.

Comment: I assume you mean you want the hash to contain `:dst => "4.2.2.2:443"`, `:src => "10.17.21.44:63314"`, `:flags => "UIO"` and, as indicated, the value of `:bytes` is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to consider:

```
IP_REGEX = '(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?::\d+)?'
input = 'TCP OUTSIDE 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO'
input.scan(/(\w+)\s(#{ IP_REGEX })/) 
# => [["OUTSIDE", "4.2.2.2:443"], ["INSIDE", "10.17.21.44:63314"]]
```

`scan` looks for the pattern given and returns an array of all matching hits. Because I'm using captures, they're returned as sub-arrays.

If you want the result to be a hash you can do:

```
input.scan(/(\w+)\s(#{ IP_REGEX })/).to_h # => {"OUTSIDE"=>"4.2.2.2:443", "INSIDE"=>"10.17.21.44:63314"}
```

or, if you're on an older Ruby that doesn't support `to_h`:

```
Hash[input.scan(/(\w+)\s(#{ IP_REGEX })/)] # => {"OUTSIDE"=>"4.2.2.2:443", "INSIDE"=>"10.17.21.44:63314"}
```

You could use a simpler `scan` pattern and allow parallel assignment help you grab the IPs in order:

```
src, dst = input.scan(/#{ IP_REGEX }/)
```

Then grab the other two fields however you want and assign them all to your hash:

```
foo = {
  src: src,
  dst: dst,
  ...
}
```

But, really, I'd take advantage of named captures:

```
matches = input.match(/(?<src>#{ IP_REGEX }) \w+ (?<dst>#{ IP_REGEX }), idle (?<idle>\S+), bytes (?<bytes>\d+), flags (?<flags>\S+)/)
# => #<MatchData
#     "4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO"
#     src:"4.2.2.2:443"
#     dst:"10.17.21.44:63314"
#     idle:"0:00:44"
#     bytes:"11365"
#     flags:"UIO">
matches['src'] # => "4.2.2.2:443"
matches['dst'] # => "10.17.21.44:63314"
matches['idle'] # => "0:00:44"
matches['bytes'] # => "11365"
matches['flags'] # => "UIO"
```

At this point `matches` acts like a hash as far as allowing access to the individual elements.

If you don't like that it's a simple step to getting a real hash:

```
matches.names.zip(matches.captures).to_h
# => {"src"=>"4.2.2.2:443",
#     "dst"=>"10.17.21.44:63314",
#     "idle"=>"0:00:44",
#     "bytes"=>"11365",
#     "flags"=>"UIO"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The goal may be achieved with one regexp:

```
▶ s='TCP OUTSIDE 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO'
# => "TCP OUTSIDE 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO"
▶ s.match('(?<proto>.*?)\s+OUTSIDE\s+(?<dst>\S+)\s+INSIDE\s+(?<src>[\d\.\:]+).*?idle\s+(?<idle>[\d\.\:]+).*?bytes\s+(?<bytes>\d+).*?flags\s+(?<flags>\S+)')
# => #<MatchData "TCP OUTSIDE 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO" proto:"TCP" dst:"4.2.2.2:443" src:"10.17.21.44:63314" idle:"0:00:44" bytes:"11365" flags:"UIO">
▶ h = {:dst => $~['dst'], :src => $~['src'], :bytes => $~['bytes'], :flags => $~['flags'] }
# => {
#  :bytes => "11365",
#  :dst => "4.2.2.2:443",
#  :flags => "UIO",
#  :src => "10.17.21.44:63314"
# }
```

Here magic `$~` variable has a direct access to [captures](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing) array.

**UPD**: You might want to go further and automate hash assignment:

```
▶ $~.names.reduce({}) { |memo, k| memo[k.to_sym] = $~[k]; memo }
# => {
#  :bytes => "11365",
#  :dst => "4.2.2.2:443",
#  :flags => "UIO",
#  :idle => "0:00:44",
#  :proto => "TCP",
#  :src => "10.17.21.44:63314"
# }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that may be easier to understand and maintain than solutions involving more complex regular expressions.

**Code**

```
def hashify_file(fname)
  IO.foreach(fname).with_object([]) { |str,arr| arr << hashify_str(str) }
end

def hashify_str(str)
  h = strip
     .sub(/\s*TCP OUTSIDE/, 'dst') # convert first key
     .sub(/\s+INSIDE/,', src')     # convert second key and insert comma
     .sub(/\s+idle[^,]+,/,'')      # remove 'idle' field
     .split(/\s*,\s+/)
     .map {|s| s.split(/\s/)
                .map { |ss|(ss =~ /[a-z]+/) ? ss.to_sym : ss } } 
     .to_h
  h[:bytes] = h[:bytes].to_i
  h
end
```

[Hash#to_h](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-to_h) became available in v. 2.1. With earlier versions use `Hash[arr]` rather than `arr.to_h`.

(Note IRB and PRY may have a problem executing this format, but it runs fine from the command line.)

**Example**

```
str = "TCP OUTSIDE 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, " +
      "idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO"

hashify_str(str)     
  #=> {:dst=>"4.2.2.2:443", :src=>"10.17.21.44:63314",
  #    :bytes=>"11365", :flags=>"UIO"}
```

**Explanation**

```
s0 = str.strip
  #=> "TCP OUTSIDE 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO"
s1 = s0.sub(/\s*TCP OUTSIDE/, 'dst')
  #=> "dst 4.2.2.2:443 INSIDE 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO"
s2 = s1.sub(/\s+INSIDE/,', src')
  #=> "dst 4.2.2.2:443, src 10.17.21.44:63314, idle 0:00:44, bytes 11365, flags UIO"
s3 = s2.sub(/\s+idle[^,]+,/,'')
  #=> "dst 4.2.2.2:443, src 10.17.21.44:63314, bytes 11365, flags UIO"
arr0 = s3.split(/\s*,\s+/)
  #=> ["dst 4.2.2.2:443", "src 10.17.21.44:63314", "bytes 11365", "flags UIO"]
arr1 = arr0.map {|s| s.split(/\s/).map {|ss|(ss =~ /[a-z]+/) ? ss.to_sym : ss}} 
  #=> [[:dst, "4.2.2.2:443"], [:src, "10.17.21.44:63314"],
  #    [:bytes, "11365"], [:flags, "UIO"]]
h = arr1.to_h
  #=> {:dst=>"4.2.2.2:443", :src=>"10.17.21.44:63314",
  #    :bytes=>"11365", :flags=>"UIO"}
h[:bytes] = h[:bytes].to_i
  #=> 11365
h
  #=> {:dst=>"4.2.2.2:443", :src=>"10.17.21.44:63314",
       :bytes=>11365, :flags=>"UIO"}
```